# Lower bounding $\mathbb{P}(X>a, Y<b)$ given $|\text{Corr}(X, Y)|$ is small

Tags: probability-theory, covariance

Suppose we want to get a lower bound for the probability $$\mathbb{P}(X>a, Y<b),$$ and let us assume $\mathbb{P}(X>a) + \mathbb{P}(Y<b) <1$, so a direct union bound would not work.

If $X$ and $Y$ were independent, then we get a lower bound which is $\mathbb{P}(X>a)\cdot \mathbb{P}(Y<b)$. Now if we only know that $|\text{Corr}(X, Y)| < \epsilon_0$, can we show that for $\epsilon_0$ is sufficiently smaller, we can obtain some form of a lower bound for $\mathbb{P}(X>a, Y<b)$?

---

In my actual setup, we have a random walk $\{Z_i\}$ with $\rho$-mixing condition, and for two disjoint collection of indices $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, I would like to lower bound
$$\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{i \in \mathcal{A}} Z_i > a, \sum_{j \in \mathcal{B}} Z_j <b\Big)$$
when the distance between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is large.

Comment: @NN2 We can assume that the variance of $X$ and $Y$ are known. But the marginal distribution of $X$ and $Y$ are not explicit. I added more details for the setup.

Comment: From what you wrote "If $X$ and $Y$ were independent, then we get a lower bound which is $\mathbb{P}(X>a)\cdot \mathbb{P}(Y<b)$", I guessed that the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ should be known (as you can compute $\mathbb{P}(X>a)$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y<b)$)? Or at least, $\mathbb{P}(X>a)$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y<b)$) are known?

Comment: To solve this problem, I think you should use the Sklar's theorem.

Comment: @NN2 Thanks, I was just looking for a bound of the form $f(P(X>a), P(Y<b)) > 0$ where $f$ can be any positive function.